# Is it possible to use socket.io for one client server interaction i.e. I do not wish to broadcast my message to all the sessions connected

Tags: flask, socket.io

I want to create an chat app that shows responses from flask app. The only purpose I am using sockets is to capture session ID. I do not want all the sessions to be connected. As all the sessions are connected I am getting extra responses,for two sessions running, extra chat dialogbox of response appears on chatbot UI. I cannot figure out a way to keep them separated. Any help will be appreciated.

app.py

```
@socketio.on('my event')
def handle_my_custom_event(json):
    print('received something' +str(json))
    print("###############################")
    print(request.sid)
    print("###############################")
    #return request.sid
    k = request.sid
    socketio.emit('server response', k)      #to client-side
    #@socketio.on('message from user', namespace='/messages')

@app.route("/get")
def get_bot_response():
    userText = request.args.get('msg')
    id = request.args.get('sess')
    print('#########'+str(request.args.get('sess')))



index.html

<script>
            //var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5000')
            var socket = io.connect(location.protocol + '//' + document.domain +':' + location.port);
            socket.on('connect', function(){
                    socket.emit('my event', {data:'User Connected'})
            })
            socket.on('server response', function(s_sess){
                    session_id = s_sess
                    console.log("@@@@@@@"+session_id)
                    //return session_id
                    function getBotResponse() {
                              var rawText = $("#message").val();
                              var userHtml = '<p class="userText"><span>' + rawText + '</span></p>';
                              $("#message").val("");
                              $("#chatbox").append(userHtml);
                              document.getElementById('userInput').scrollIntoView({block: 'start', behavior: 'smooth'});
                              $.get("/get", {msg: rawText, sess: session_id}).done(function(data) {
                                var botHtml = '<p class="botText"><span>' + data + '</span></p>';
                                $("#chatbox").append(botHtml);
                                document.getElementById('userInput').scrollIntoView({block: 'start', behavior: 'smooth'});
                              });
                            }

                     // send button or enter
                    $("#message").keypress(function(e) {
                                    if(e.which == 13) {
                                    getBotResponse();
                                    }
                               });
                        $("#send").click(function() {
                          getBotResponse();
                          })
                    })

        </script>
```

I wish to implement one to one flask chat app and also need session id for further purpose. Please assist.